# Does this sentence need an article before the noun phrase?

Tags: articles

Which is correct:

> I think every day we will do different topic

or

> I think every day we will do **a** different topic.

I know that each noun should have an article, and here the words "different topic" are considered as a noun, but I am confused because I am not native English speaker and sometimes I see people write or say it without an article, so I have a doubt about this such sentence if it needs an article or not.

Comment: As I know we can use singular nouns without a definite article when they are noncount. Here topic is count so better not use it as a bare noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the phrase "different topic", "topic" is the noun and "different" is the adjective describing the noun.

In this case you **should** include the article (because it signals the noun), and "topic" is **countable** (so you must use a, an, or a quantity). For example:

> - ... we will do **a** different topic
> - You will get **an** alpaca

or you can use a determiner:

> - I will buy **some/a few/many/etc** donkey**s**

Of course, you don't have to (although you can) use an article/determiner when the noun is uncountable, for example:

> - I'm doing *work*
> - I will drink *water*